# Highcharts Showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')

Tags: highcharts

I've had this HighCharts spider chart working fine for a while now, but we upgraded to the latest HighCharts code and I noticed that the mouseovers are no longer working.  My PHP code looks like this:

```
    // Create a new Highchart
    $chart = new Highchart();
    $chart->includeExtraScripts();

    $chart->chart->renderTo = "control_maturity_spider_chart";
    $chart->chart->polar = true;
    $chart->chart->type = "line";
    $chart->chart->width = 1000;
    $chart->chart->height = 1000;
    $chart->title->text = "Current vs Desired Maturity by Control Family";
    $chart->title->x = -80;
    $chart->pane->size = "80%";
    $chart->xAxis->categories = $categories;
    $chart->xAxis->tickmarkPlacement = "on";
    $chart->xAxis->lineWidth = 0;
    $chart->yAxis->gridLineInterpolation = "polygon";
    $chart->yAxis->lineWidth = 0;
    $chart->yAxis->min = 0;
    $chart->yAxis->max = 5;
    $chart->yAxis->tickInterval = 1;
    $chart->tooltip->shared = true;
    $chart->tooltip->pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>';
    $chart->legend->align = "center";
    $chart->legend->verticalAlign = "top";
    $chart->legend->layout = "vertical";

    // Draw the Current Maturity series
    $chart->series[0]->name = $escaper->escapeHtml($lang['CurrentControlMaturity']);
    $chart->series[0]->data = empty($categories_current_maturity_average) ? [] : $categories_current_maturity_average;
    $chart->series[0]->pointPlacement = "on";

    // Draw the Desired Maturity series
    $chart->series[1]->name = $escaper->escapeHtml($lang['DesiredControlMaturity']);
    $chart->series[1]->data = empty($categories_desired_maturity_average) ? [] : $categories_desired_maturity_average;
    $chart->series[1]->pointPlacement = "on";

    $chart->credits->enabled = false;

    echo "<figure class=\"highcharts-figure\">\n";
    echo "  <div id=\"control_maturity_spider_chart\"></div>\n";
    echo "</figure>\n";

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    echo $chart->render("control_maturity_spider_chart");
    echo "</script>\n";
```

The actual chart renders just fine, but if you mouse over it, you just get this message in the javascript console over and over again:

[HighCharts Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBIC4.png)

If we comment out these two lines of code, the mouseover works:

```
    $chart->tooltip->shared = true;
    $chart->tooltip->pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>';
```

Any thoughts on what we are doing wrong here, or what changed, would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the bug which you can track here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17472

As a temporary workaround, add the following wrap function to your code:

```
(function(H) {
  const isObject = H.isObject;
  H.Pointer.prototype.findNearestKDPoint = function(series, shared, e) {
    var chart = this.chart;
    var hoverPoint = chart.hoverPoint;
    var tooltip = chart.tooltip;
    if (hoverPoint &&
      tooltip &&
      tooltip.isStickyOnContact()) {
      return hoverPoint;
    }
    var closest;
    /** @private */
    function sort(p1, p2) {
      var isCloserX = p1.distX - p2.distX,
        isCloser = p1.dist - p2.dist,
        isAbove = ((p2.series.group && p2.series.group.zIndex) -
          (p1.series.group && p1.series.group.zIndex));
      var result;
      // We have two points which are not in the same place on xAxis
      // and shared tooltip:
      if (isCloserX !== 0 && shared) { // #5721
        result = isCloserX;
        // Points are not exactly in the same place on x/yAxis:
      } else if (isCloser !== 0) {
        result = isCloser;
        // The same xAxis and yAxis position, sort by z-index:
      } else if (isAbove !== 0) {
        result = isAbove;
        // The same zIndex, sort by array index:
      } else {
        result =
          p1.series.index > p2.series.index ?
          -1 :
          1;
      }
      return result;
    }
    series.forEach(function(s) {
      var noSharedTooltip = s.noSharedTooltip && shared,
        compareX = (!noSharedTooltip &&
          s.options.findNearestPointBy.indexOf('y') < 0),
        point = s.searchPoint.call(s.polar, e, compareX);
      if ( // Check that we actually found a point on the series.
        isObject(point, true) && point.series &&
        // Use the new point if it is closer.
        (!isObject(closest, true) ||
          (sort(closest, point) > 0))) {
        closest = point;
      }
    });
    return closest;
  };
}(Highcharts))
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8b2mhqf0/